# torch squeeze, narrow, slice?

Tags: numpy, pytorch, tensor, torchvision

I have an array of images which I run a deep learning model on to get some tensors of predictions in pytorch.  Is there a good newb tutorial here on tensors and shapes/reshaping?

```
x = prediction['masks']
```

This object I know contains the masks of the object detection prediction.. but I am unclear how to proceed to extract a mask at a time to multiply that mask over my image I've just run inference on.

[image]

I am just playing around for now with 1 image in the entire batch.. but the 0th dimension at the beginning is throwing me off here.. I looked at trying to `torch.squeeze(x,0)` but that did nothing

in the end I want to just multiple my mask as an opencv or numpy array/matrix.. over the inference test image like so..

```
dst = opencvimage * mask_img

cv2.imshow('image', dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

opencvimage is an `ndarray: (9212,1631,3)` which sounds reasonable RGB or BGR format..

**EDIT - adding how the tensor was made**

Here is the important scoring function.. It sounds like I should fiddle here when I am packing the tensor to get rid of the `0th dim` shape axis

```
   images = ImageDataset(paths_to_images, transform=transform)
    loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(images, batch_size=1, num_workers=1)

    all_predictions = []
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch in loader:
            predictions = list(model(batch.to(device)))
            for prediction in predictions:
                all_predictions.append(prediction)

    #  Take predictions and masks and draw on the images

    return predictions
```

Reading it now.. it appears the prediction for masks is empty.. meaning I need to revisit the tutorial I supposed.. or how I've loaded things

I added a check to look at the boxes.. they too appear to come out empty??

[image]

Comment: Can you show how you create this tensor with the 0 dimension ? Because it is basically a tensor which contains no element

Comment: @trialNerror good eye, I've made a note to go back and examine how I've compiled the predictions.. I've attached it now to the post at the end